# Суммировать стоимость на Python

Tags: python

Сижу над задачей второй день, не как не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы можно было ввести название допустим 2 или 3 пицц, и в конце выводилось бы общая сумма этих пицц.
И при этом чтоб код был максимально логичным и без лишних строк.
Буду очень благодарен ответу, и если кто-то может дать какой-то совет или конструктивную критику буду так же благодарен.

```
class Pizzeria():
   Класс для создагия и расчета пиццы

    def __init__ (self,pizza_name,pizza_cost,pizza_topping = ""):
        """создание пиццы и добавление ее в словарь"""
        self.pizza_name = pizza_name
        self.pizza_cost = pizza_cost
        self.pizza_topping = pizza_topping
        self.pizza_costt = 0
        self.order_piz = ""


        pizza = {
            "Pizza_names" : pizza_name,
            "Pizza_topping" : pizza_topping,
            "Pizza_cost" : pizza_cost,

        }



    def order_pizza():

        order_piz = ""

        while order_piz != 'quit':

            order_piz = input (f"Pleas enter pizza name here\n(if you like to "
                               f"finished enter 'quit: ")
            if order_piz == ('salami'):
                salami = Pizzeria("salami",5.56)
                salami.bill(salami.pizza_cost)
            if order_piz == 'ham':
                ham = Pizzeria("Ham",6.89)
                ham.bill(ham.pizza_cost)

            if order_piz == 'quit':
                print (len(order_piz))

        return order_piz

    def bill(self, pizza_cost ):

        order_piz = self.order_piz

        while order_piz == 'quit':
            self.pizza_costt += pizza_cost

        print (pizza_cost)
"""
```

Comment: К чему у вас относятся функции order_pizza и bill? к классу Pizzeria?

Comment: Да, к классу Pizzeria

Comment: А что ? это не правильно?

Comment: А вас не смущает, что вы объявляете класс, а потом внутри него ссылаетесь на его же экземпляр? Вы точно понимаете, что делаете?